# Gimp not working after ubuntu 16.04 update

Tags: gimp

I installed gimp while on version 15.10 and it worked fine and now after a long time when I tried to open it after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04, it fails to open and a pop comes saying it has crashed.

I tried reinstalling from the terminal and from software center both times it installed fine but just wont open.

When I tried to open it from the terminal I got -

```
gimp: /build/beignet-5qGeBM/beignet-1.1.1/src/intel/intel_driver.c:140: intel_driver_context_init: Assertion `driver->ctx' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: There are a few bug reports which may be related: [#1559396](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1559396), [#1564697](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1564697) and [#1567007](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1567007).

Comment: I can add that Gimp works for me on a (relatively) fresh 16.04. Did you upgrade from 15.10?

Comment: The error message indicates a problem with the OpenCL driver for your CPU.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after triying to compile another program, gimp stop working, the problem for me was the library **ocl-icd-opencl-dev** i just unninstalled and problem solve, gimp works again.